# Почему в tkinter возникает ошибка Bad entry index "1.0"?

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно вставить в `Entry` и `Text` текст из файлов, но tkinter очень непонятно себя ведет ругается на плохой индекс. Я попробовал все варианты:

> "0.1", "1.0", 0, 1, 1.0, 0.1, 0.0

Ничего не работает. Правда, ошибка происходит именно при попытке заполнить текст `Entry`, а при тех же операциях с Text программа нормально работает. Вот часть программы:

```
import tkinter, realize_Grons
import os


def open_test():
    """Функция проверки файла на пустоту, для восстановления
    раннее введеных данных(Текст, Ключ)"""
    # для проверки файла на пустоту, используем библиотеку os
    print("Yes_01")
    if os.stat("keys_here").st_size != 0 and os.stat("text_here").st_size != 0:
        print("Yes_02")
        with open("keys_here", mode="r", encoding="latin_1") as f:
            key.insert(index="1.0", string=f.read())
        with open("text_here", mode="r", encoding="latin_1") as f:
            input_text.insert(index="1.0", chars=f.read())
    elif os.stat("keys_here").st_size != 0:
        print("Yes_03")
        with open("keys_here", mode="r", encoding="latin_1") as f:
            key.insert(index="1.0", string=f.read())
    elif os.stat("text_here").st_size != 0:
        print("Yes_04")
        with open("text_here", mode="r", encoding="latin_1") as f:
            input_text.insert(index="1.0", chars=f.read())


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Шифр Гронсфельда")

frame_1 = tkinter.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame_2 = tkinter.Frame(root, bg="white")
label_to_input_text = tkinter.Label(frame_1, text="Введите текст: ")
label_to_output_text = tkinter.Label(frame_1, text="Зашифрованный текст: ")
input_text = tkinter.Text(frame_1, width=40, height=20, bg="white")
output_text = tkinter.Text(frame_1, width=40, height=20, bg="white")
output_text.config(state="disabled")
# перенос слова в окне ввода текста
input_text.config(wrap="word")

label = tkinter.Label(frame_2, text="Введите Ключ смещения: ", width=20, bg="white")
key = tkinter.Entry(frame_2)
encrypt_it = tkinter.Button(frame_2, text="Зашифровать!")
# инилциализируем переменные для checkbox
var_1 = tkinter.IntVar()
var_2 = tkinter.IntVar()
# описание checkbox
user_choice_1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(frame_2, text="Сохранить Ключ", variable=var_1)
user_choice_2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(frame_2, text="Сохранить Текст", variable=var_2)


# Настройка frame_1 and frame_2
frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame_2.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Настройка объектов frame_1
label_to_input_text.pack()
input_text.pack()
label_to_output_text.pack()
output_text.pack()


# Настройка объектов frame_2
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
key.grid(row=1, column=0)
encrypt_it.grid(row=2, column=0)
user_choice_1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")
user_choice_2.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="w")

open_test()

# обработка событий
encrypt_it.bind("<Button-1>", crupte_it)


# обработка выхода из приложения
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_exit)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: index должен быть целым числом либо строкой содержащей целое число и указывает на позицию вставки строки

Comment: @godva . Заменил все Entry на индекс `0` и заработало. Спасибо, правда очень странно что для Text сработал тип float, подозреваю это связанно с тем, что в случае с Text там представление идет в виде таблице, потому что строк много и надо тип float, а у Entry - 1 строка и тип int, но это не точно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Виджет Entry**

Как отмечено выше:

> index должен быть **целым числом, либо строкой**, содержащей целое число, и указывает на позицию вставки строки

[The Tkinter Entry Widget](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

**Виджет Text**

В Text-виджете индекс представляется **строкой с двумя числами**, разделёнными точкой:

```
"%d.%d" % (line, column)
```

При этом номера строк начинаются с 1, номера столбцов - с 0.

[The Tkinter Text Widget](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)